# How can i change github token in my project by github bash on windows10?

Tags: git, github, token

I sign in github by my coworker's token.

Now I want to push my data into my private repository, the permission is denied because token registered is not mine but my coworker's.
So I want to register my token into this desktop.

How can I do it?

People says "if you do push, the sign in step will come up". But when I tried push, no sign in came up and only `permission denied, 403 error` occured.

Comment: `403 error` implies that you're using https. This means you're using a *credential helper*. Which one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.